# Multiple linux shutdown schedule and its behavior

Tags: linux, shutdown

If I schedule shutdown multiple times, what will the behavior be? For example:

```
shutdown +20
shutdown +25
```

Does the second shutdown command override the first one?

Also what if I cancel shutdown by using shutdown -c? For example

```
shutdown +20
shutdown +25
shutdown -c
```

Will it cancel all of the shutdown schedules or just the last one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the 'shutdown' command provided by *systemd:*

- There is one centrally-managed shutdown timer (managed by the *systemd-logind* service). Trying to schedule a shutdown multiple times will just automatically cancel and replace the timeout & action with the new parameters.
- `shutdown +XX` calls systemd-logind's ScheduleShutdown(), which sets or adjusts the timer.
- `shutdown -c` calls systemd-logind's CancelScheduledShutdown(), which disables the timer.

If you're using the [shutdown](https://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/sysvinit.git/tree/src/shutdown.c) command from Linux sysvinit:

- The program uses a pid-file to make sure a shutdown can only be scheduled once. If you try to run it twice, you should get the message "shutdown: already running". (Unless you accidentally deleted the pidfile that it uses to keep track of things.)
- `shutdown +XX` refuses to start a new "queued shutdown" process if it finds one already running in background (according to the PID stored in /var/run/shutdown.pid).
- `shutdown -c` kills exactly one "queued shutdown" process (whose PID is read from shutdown.pid), under the assumption that you shouldn't have been able to start more than one.